# Unity3d Using a different device for rendering and displaying

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, display, virtual-reality

Our project consists of very detailed models and we are supposed to show it in a android device. We are using VR cardboard.

The project has become quiet large and it's starting to lag in the mobile phone. We are still  add more models and effects.

We need a way such that the game runs on a pc and displayed on android device so that everything runs smoothly. The game needs to access gyroscope and other sensors for VR.

**Can It be done?**

Answer (score 1):

Yea. [Unity Remote](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html) is there to help you with just that.

Comment: Unity Remote is more like a testing tool. Isn't there a way after the applicaition is built And instead of usb connection using WLAN?

Comment: You can use Unity Remote Wirelessly. [Here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/wireless-unity-remote-root-only.229100/) is an article explaining how.